# User-defined variable in a query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've been working on a project that includes lots of summary statistics.  One thing that would be very helpful for me would be to have a variable set equal to the result of a query that appeared on every line.  Something like

```
declare @totalpop int
set @totalpop = select count(*) as [population]
from myTable

select sex, count(sex), @totalpop
from myTable
```

ninja edit on the query i tried, but it failed.  Error is incorrect syntax near the keyword select

Comment: Add parenthesis to the query where you set the variable (select count(*) as [population] 
from myTable )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last paragraph, this seems to be what you want:

```
SELECT tsum.*, sum(cnt) over (partition by NULL) as TotalPop
FROM (SELECT gender, count(*) as cnt
      FROM t
      GROUP BY gender
     ) tsum
```

The expression with the "over" clause is a window function that adds up all the windows.

Comment: This works just like I want.  Is there not a way to approach the problem as I was trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT gender, count(gender) AS countGender, @totalPop AS totalPop 
FROM myTable  
GROUP BY gender
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT gender, count(gender), @totalPop
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `@` for variables, I assume you're using Sql Server. The following script returns a single row, with 3 columns (one for each count). I know it is not exactly what you requested, but I guess it is an easy way to return the same information:

```
DECLARE @COUNT_TOTAL INT;
DECLARE @COUNT_MALE INT;
DECLARE @COUNT_FEMALE INT;

SELECT @COUNT_TOTAL = COUNT(*)
  @COUNT_MALE = SUM(CASE WHEN gender='MALE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  @COUNT_FEMALE = SUM(CASE WHEN gender='FEMALE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
FROM myTable;

SELECT @COUNT_TOTAL AS [COUNT_TOTAL]
    , @COUNT_MALE AS [COUNT_MALE]
    , @COUNT_FEMALE AS [COUNT_FEMALE];
```

Comment: I am indeed new to SQL Server.  Could you point me to some literature why @ is bad for assigning variables?

Comment: Actually, using `@` is the **only** way to create and use variables in T-SQL. The problem with your query was the syntax. I updated the sample to store the values into local variables.

Comment: Thanks, kind sir.  I've only just begun using SQL